# How to make BarLegend colors conform with MatrixPlot ones?

Tags: color, legending, visualization

It is needed to visualize some data set and built a color bar for describing the data values. The following array is given

```
TestArray = {{0.0288, 0.0413, 0.0772, 0.0369, 0.0296, 0.029, 0.0294, 
0.0334, 0.0771, 0.0755}, {0.0311, 0.0363, 0.0874, 0.0324, 0.025, 
0.0432, 0.0602, 0.0498, 0.1174, 0.2587}, {0.0291, 0.0452, 0.0484, 
0.0372, 0.0182, 0.0971, 0.0688, 0.0561, 0.0303, 0.0382}, {0.0174, 
0.0494, 0.0378, 0.0244, 0.0637, 0.0667, 0.1013, 0.0247, 0.0266, 
0.092}, {0.0234, 0.0118, 0.0235, 0.0239, 0.0336, 0.0498, 0.0366, 
0.0578, 0.0431, 0.0859}};
```

TestArray is visualized by the MatrixPlot function

```
MatrixPlot[TestArray, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]
```

[image]

Next, the color bar is built

```
BarLegend[{"ThermometerColors", {0, Max[TestArray]}}, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold}, LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
```

[image]

However, the color bar does not conform with the plot: array has entries with values below 0.05, but they aren't blue on the plot according to the bar. 
How to make them conform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BarLegend[{ColorData["ThermometerColors"]@Rescale[#, MinMax@TestArray, {.5, 1}] &, 
      MinMax@TestArray}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontWeight -> Bold}, 
 LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
```

[image: legend]

An easier way to get the legend is to use the option `PlotLegends` in `MatrixPlot` and extract the legend:

```
MatrixPlot[TestArray, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors", 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
      FontWeight -> Bold}, LegendFunction -> "Frame"]][[2, 1]]
```

[image: legend]

**Note:** Color scaling in `MatrixPlot` is quite different from other plot functions. See
[Matrix Plot >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPlot.html#8203089) for an explanation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works

Comment: Surely, your answer is very helpful !